# Can any glyphicon just be a single path?

Tags: xml, svg, vector, graphics, glyphicons

I'm talking about a monochromatic icon in svg format. An example of this would be the icons on the upper right corner of the stackoverflow website.

I noticed that all the icons on twitter bootstrap are just a single path (even if they are comprised of many elements):
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

```
  <path d="M250 700h800q21 0 35.5 -14.5t14.5 -35.5v-200q0 -21 -14.5 -35.5t-35.5 -14.5h-800q-21 0 -35.5 14.5t-14.5 35.5v200q0 21 14.5 35.5t35.5 14.5z" />
```

But other icon sets like: 
https://glyph.smarticons.co/

Their glyphicons are comprised of multiple elements:

```
<path d="M7.984,0.053 C3.599,0.053 0.045,3.614 0.045,8.006 C0.045,12.398 3.6,15.959 7.984,15.959 C12.368,15.959 15.923,12.398 15.923,8.006 C15.923,3.614 12.369,0.053 7.984,0.053 L7.984,0.053 Z M7.49,2.045 C8.328,2.045 9.009,2.699 9.009,3.505 C9.009,4.311 8.328,4.965 7.49,4.965 C6.65,4.965 5.971,4.311 5.971,3.505 C5.971,2.699 6.65,2.045 7.49,2.045 L7.49,2.045 Z M8.035,14.908 C4.984,14.908 2.342,10.918 8.101,7.984 C13.357,5.308 10.904,0.744 8.035,1.008 C12.41,1.008 14.974,4.119 14.974,7.958 C14.975,11.797 11.867,14.908 8.035,14.908 L8.035,14.908 Z" class="si-glyph-fill"></path>
<ellipse cx="8.493" cy="11.445" rx="1.493" ry="1.445" class="si-glyph-fill"></ellipse>
```

I noticed using a vector program I can turn objects into path and then combine all paths.

But I'm wondering if it's theoretically possible that every glyphicon can be converted into a single path this way? Or are there situations where an icon cannot be?

Comment: For some paths you will need a fill-rule="evenodd" in order to see the "holes". But in this case the original drawing needs to be drawn in a specific way. To be more specific the fragments of path have to be drawn in opposite direction in order to be able to see the holes. There is yet an other problem: some glyphicons may contain not only paths but also circles, elipses. . . etc. In this case you will need a way to transform those primitives into paths.

Comment: @enxaneta my understanding is that any object (circle, elipses) can be converted to paths using a vector program. and that multiple paths can be converted into a single path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly example: you have 2 simple svg images. The first has only one path. For the second one I've taken the points from the first SVG and I've made 2 paths. The 2 images look alike.

```css
svg{display:inline-block;border:1px,solid;}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="300">
  <path id="test" d="M50,50L250,100L150,200L30,250z
                     M100,100 L120 180L170,170z"/>
  
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="300">
  <path id="test" d="M50,50L250,100L150,200L30,250z"/>
  <path id="test" d="M100,100 L120 180L170,170z" />
  
</svg>
```

Now you remove the stroke and let the fill to be black:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="300">
  <path id="test" d="M50,50L250,100L150,200L30,250z
                     M100,100 L120 180L170,170z" />
  
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="300">
  <path id="test" d="M50,50L250,100L150,200L30,250z"/>
  <path id="test" d="M100,100 L120 180L170,170z" />
  
</svg>
```